# How to watch videos in 144p, 240p, 360p, 480p, 720p on YouTube app?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, youtube, video-streaming

While watching videos in browser it shows me options of 144p, 240p, 360p, 480p, 720p and so on. But on YouTube app for Android I only see option of HD/HQ (I assume its High Definition / High Quality).

How can I watch videos in 144p, 240p, 360p, 480p, 720p on YouTube app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Those quality settings only apply to the desktop version. Mobile apps use a different set of videos, which are already optimized for mobile devices, and have two different quality settings, regular and HD.

Answer (score 2):

The years have passed since the OP asked the question. Since then things have changed.
It is possible to select the quality of the video.

When playing a video, click the 3-dot on the right top corner. Select Quality, then choose the video quality.

***Note:*** Some video qualities will not be shown if your device can't handle them.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a modified version of the official YouTube version 4 app, it has an option to let you choose the preferred quality

[image: Choosing preffered quality easily]

[Official XDA threab](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2213945), credits goes to xda member Osama Ghareeb

Please note that this app is built on the fourth version of the official app and the latest version is 5.