# Allow 720p videos on YouTube app

Tags: youtube

My device is Atrix 2 with resolution of 960x540, but YouTube app only gives me options for 144p, 240p and 360p, which are not really "quality". How can I watch 720p videos on YouTube on my device?

Comment: Do the videos you're watching come in 720p?

Comment: Yes, sure. It's every video that I try to watch that can be viewed in only 144p, 240p or 360p. So I gave up on off. app and installed "Viral" but it's not working good right now, so I wan't to try and fix off. app for good.

Comment: Probably related (although outdated): [How to watch videos in 144p, 240p, 360p, 480p, 720p on YouTube app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56128/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT. For the accepted answer I'd say that it's outdated, but about modded YouTube - maybe I should try that while I search for the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Your screen resolution being 960*540 is not meant to play 720p videos  because the resolution is lower. That's why the Youtube app detects the device resolution and does not show higher video qualities. The maximum video quality that the Youtube app will show for your device is 480p.

```
720p = 1280*720
```

However, you could use [YouTube Vanced](https://youtubevanced.com/). It is a modded version that offers more features than the official Youtube app such as:

> - Override Maximal Resolution
> - Preferred Speed and Resolution

For rooted phones, [L Tweaks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=li.lingfeng.ltweaks), an Xposed module, allows to set video qualities up to 4320p.